# Embeded Video No Longer Works

Tags: facebook, embed, facebook-opengraph

So we have a series of movie trailers that we have been embedding in Facebook, and they worked up until the recent changes. This means, when you embedded them, they displayed an image and you could play the video.

Now they suddenly stopped working. I have gone over the Open Graph tags, and they seem correct, but obviously something is missing.

Do you see anything with this link that is in error http://www.totaleclips.com/test-Player/Facebook.aspx?eclipid=e95147&bitrateid=267&vendorid=1011&FB=1

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only/core issue but your `og:url` tag is pointing to `http://www.Image-Entertainment.com` which means Facebook will go to THAT url and take the tags from there - the og:url tag should point to the canonical URL for a piece of content

In this case, if it's just a test it should probably point to `http://www.totaleclips.com/test-Player/Facebook.aspx?eclipid=e95147&bitrateid=267&vendorid=1011&FB=1` - in production it should probably point to whichever URL is the permanent URL for the video, that URL must have the correct meta tags (also).

You should run your URL through the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) - it may not always be entirely clear what the issue is (especially where there's HTTP or og:url redirects taking place) but it shows what Facebook is detecting on your page

Comment: Thanks @Igy.<br/>  When you say that the "URL must have the correct meta tags", I'm not sure what you are saying. Which meta tags are you referring to? <br/>  I have been using that Facebook debugger, but keeps throwing errors that don't make sense like "The og:url property is required, but not present." but it is, so not sure what to believe. Any advice there?

Comment: Do you have the og:url meta tag on the page you're debugging? bear in mind that the debugger follows 301 and og:url redirects (i.e if you have an og:url tag on page A pointing to page B, but no meta tags on page B, you'll get an error)